# Can I get LogParser 2.2 to export into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, iis, logging, logparser

I've got an IIS site running with a MySQL db.  Is there a way to get logparser to export into a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LogParser can output CSV and most databases should be able to import from a CSV file, this should be possible. I'm not that familiar with MySQL but I found a thread on the iss.net forums which discusses how to do this:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1166385.aspx

"...try... outputting data as CSV and then using [MYSQLIMPORT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to get the data into MySQL."

Answer (score 0):

The "SQL" output format dumps results to any ODBC-compatible database. You can see its options by using the following command:

```
LogParser -h -o:SQL
```